# Get single property from HTTP Observable response

Tags: angular, rxjs

This should be an easy one for you RxJS pros.

I am using Angular 5.

I want to do something like this:

```
  this.allFilters = this.http.get(path).pipe(
    map((response) => response.forms.sim_filter.schema.properties))
```

The response is a bog standard object, not an array so I'm not sure that map is right.

So basically, I am only interested in a deeply nested property and only want to have access to that when I subscribe to `this.allFilters`

How do I do it, please?

Comment: map seems to be correct. what does it return now

Comment: So ... where's the problem?

Comment: You are maybe confusing the array map function and the rxjs map operator.

Comment: thanks guys, map was right I was clearly doing something stupid, not sure what but its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't related to Rx, this more of a JS question.

`allFilters` is an Observable in your code, that you have assigned through an HTTP call.

When you subscribe to it, you will receive what is returned in your piped `map`, in your case :

```
this.allFilters = this.http.get(path).pipe(
  map((response) => response.forms.sim_filter.schema.properties))

this.allFilters.subscribe (res => { /* res = originalResponse.forms.sim_filter.schema.properties */});
```

You can use `map` because this isn't related to JS Object/Array, but to RxJS itslef (this is an Rx operator). This could have been called `RxJSmap`, this is just a wanted coincidence.

Other than that, I don't get what your question is. What isn't working ? What are you expecting ? Could you explain a bit more ?